# When I open a batch File that is supossed to create another file with python, python opens it but it doesn't create the file

Tags: python, batch-file

```
import os
import time


def FindTask():
    while True:
        os.startfile('C:\\Users\\Joze\\Desktop\\League Bot\\TaskFinder.bat')
        time.sleep(2)
        from errorlevel import h
        if h == 0:
            print("is")
        elif h == 1:
            print("no")

FindTask()
```

`TaskFinder.bat` is supossed to create a file named **`errorlevel.py`**.

The debugger does not show any errors so the file is being opened, but it doesn't create a file.

I have tried using `subprocess` but didn't work either.

Inside the batch file there is :

```
@tasklist | find /i "WinRAR.exe"
@echo h = %errorlevel% > errorlevel.py
```

Comment: And what is inside your `TaskFinder.bat` then ?

Comment: @shotgunner I edited the post, you can check it now

Comment: You should probably just directly call `find /i winrar.exe` using e.g. `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)`.

Comment: @AKX I basically wanna find if a task is open or not. If I use tasklist | find /i "WinRAR.exe" I find the task, then with %errorlevel% I either get 0 if the task is open or 1 if the task is not. I wanna get that value into a variable in a python file so I can use it for my python project. If there's a better way to check if a task is open or not, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to directly use

```
cp = subprocess.run('tasklist | find /i "WinRAR.exe"', shell=True)
print(cp.returncode)
```

instead of calling the batch script.

Even better would be not to shell out at all but use e.g. the [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) library to find the process(es) directly in Python.

Answer (score 0):

When I executed the same code it worked for me, I am using python 3, maybe this is the problem.

If it's not that I am not sure that I know why TaskFinder.bat is not opening for you a new file, but I bet it is something in the Operating System, it is probably this because it's not python.